# Logging into a website using a POST request in Objective C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

I know there's a lot of tutorials out there that try to explain this process, but I must be missing some key point about being able to log into a specific website

Here is my code to make the request:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$ctrlCustomerLogin$LoginForm$UserName=%@&ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$ctrlCustomerLogin$LoginForm$Password=%@",usernameBox.text,passwordBox.text];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.theWebsite/login.aspx"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And in

`connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`

I log the response, which is just the source for the login page, so I'd assume the login didn't go through

this is the username inputBox element:
`<input name="ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$ctrlCustomerLogin$LoginForm$UserName" type="text"`            `id="ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_ctrlCustomerLogin_LoginForm_UserName" class="textBox">`

and for the password inputBox:

`<input name="ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$ctrlCustomerLogin$LoginForm$Password" type="password"` `maxlength="50" id="ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_ctrlCustomerLogin_LoginForm_Password"` `class="textBox">`

So I looked at a similar post on here and tried it in this format:

```
 [request setValue:usernameBox.text forHTTPHeaderField:@"ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$ctrlCustomerLogin$LoginForm$UserName"];
[request setValue:passwordBox.text forHTTPHeaderField:@"ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$ctrlCustomerLogin$LoginForm$Password"];
```

Again, just returns the source of the login page. My question is (and I'm sure others must have this issue as well) am I missing something in the formatting of the POST request? Do I need to invoke the click of the "login" button, or something similar? Am I using `NSURLConnection` class incorrectly?

Also - this website does not use authentication challenge